# Trying to understand why my custom function seems to be ignoring most of it's arguments

Tags: j

Defining a simple fibonacci function as:

```
fib=: verb : '{. (({: , +/ )^:y) 0 1'
```

I expected to be able to call it as

```
   fib 5 6 7   NB. expected 5 8 13
```

but instead I get

```
   fib 5 6 7
5 8
```

Trying to understand what is going on here

Comment: You are `{.`ing the wrong axis. Just append `"1` to it and it will work `fib=: verb : '{."1 (({: , +/ )^:y) 0 1'`

Comment: thank you!  that did it.  still building my intuition on that sort of thing

Comment: @madeofmistake you can use J's visual debugger to see this kind of things.

Comment: do you have a link to a getting started guide or other resources?  i find it hard to search for "j" things unless i know exactly what i want

Comment: @madeofmistake maybe https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Books?

Comment: is this what you mean by the visual debugger?  https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/Dissect